# Ruby on Rails for post value of textbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any body tell me how should I get post value from a textbox and pass it to controller putting in if condition but no output is coming

home/index.html.erb

```
  <%text_field_tag (:text1,nil,placeholder,"Enter the username")%>
```

controller/home_controller.rb

```
   def create
   @data = parmas[:text1]
    if(@data=="abc")
    (login to another page)
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all put = sign before text_field_tag. You are using home controller which mostly used for static pages. To get this value you have to put this in form tag like this:

```
<%= form_tag root_path do %>
<%= text_field_tag (:text1,nil,placeholder,"Enter the username")%>
<%= submit_tag :search %>
<% end %>
```